# Write only numbers from textbox input to an output file in PHP

Tags: php

I use the standard output code for my output:

```
<?php
$txt = "data.txt"; 
$fh = fopen($txt, 'w+'); 
if (isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) { // check if both fields are set
   $txt=$_POST['field1'].' - '.$_POST['field2']; 
   file_put_contents('data.txt',$txt."\n",FILE_APPEND); // log to data.txt 
   exit();
}
fwrite($fh,$txt); // Write information to the file
fclose($fh); // Close the file
?>
```

My question is how to write only digits from the input in the textbox to my output. For example, when I type in my textbox `hello world547457457`, I need only `547457457` to be written to the output file.

Comment: `if ($_POST['field1'] >= 0 && $_POST['field1'] <= 9)`?

Comment: Can you discribe your problem a bit more?

Comment: when i type in my textbox hello world547457457 i need only 547457457

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This PHP script will help you but what I am suggesting is to add JavaScript validation on the input box and check it while entering the text.

```
<?php

//the text what you want
$_POST['field1'] = 'helloworld547457457';

$number = '';

//process each character
for($i=0; $i<strlen($_POST['field1']); $i++)
{
    //find the ascii value
    $ascii = ord($_POST['field1'][$i]);

    //check the number range
    if($ascii>=ord(0) && $ascii<=ord(9))
    {
        //bind the actual number
        $number .= $_POST['field1'][$i];    
    }

}

//display the output
echo $number;
```